# what is the most terse way to return an array of entities in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to figure out the most terse way to return an array of objects from a ts function.  The following function works as expected:

```
    getAuthors1(): Author[]
    {
        var authors: Author[] =
            [
                {
            FirstName: "John";
            MI: "J";        
            LastName: "Smith";                    
                }
            ];
        return authors;
    }
```

The following function errors out b/c it appears that ts won't let me return an object array directly as opposed to as a variable:

```
    getAuthors2(): Author[]
    {
        return Author[] =
            [
                {
            FirstName: "John";  
            MI: "J";        
            LastName: "Smith";                    
                }
            ];
    }
```

The following function errors out b/c a value isn't provided for MI:

```
getAuthors3(): Author[]
{
    var authors: Author[] =
        [
            {
        FirstName: "John";      
        LastName: "Smith";                    
            }
        ];
    return authors;
}
```

Questions:

1. Are values required for all object properties when creating an object initialized array?
   1a. If this is the case do developers typically initialize property values in the class?
2. Is there a way to return an object array directly, similar to my getAuthors2() example above, as opposed to having to assign this to a variable and then return the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an interface defined and you create an object where you tell TypeScript that it should be of that type, it will complain for any missing property, as it should.

One way to get around this is to use a *mapped type* where you state that each property of the object is optional, and use it like **Partial< Author >**. See the [official documentation for more info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html).

You can return the array right away, just remove the type that you've added after return:

```
getAuthors2(): Author[] {
    return [
      {
        FirstName: 'John',
        MI: 'J',
        LastName: 'Smith',
      }
    ];
  }
```

Also wherever possible you should remove the manually defined types, like the return Author[] from your functions. TypeScript will use [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) to figure it out by itself.

In your specific example either you leave the return type defined, and typescript will make the required checks or use something similar to what you have in *getAuthors3*. If you get or have the objects already typed just place them in the array and TypeScript will do the rest:

```
getAuthors() {
    const author: Author = {
        FirstName: 'John',
        MI: 'J',
        LastName: 'Smith',
    };
    return [author];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the array, not the result of an array assignment.

```js
function getAuthors() {
  return [{
    FirstName: "John",
    MI: "J",
    LastName: "Smith"
  }];
}

console.log(getAuthors());
```

Comment: Thanks Will.  But if I need to set the return value of the function to property of type Author[] then will ts know how to implicitly convert the generic objects being returned into Author classes?

Comment: You can set the return type on the function. I removed it because the 'Run Code Snipped' doesn't have a TypeScript option (or I haven't found it yet). Also, TypeScript will infer the return type because it can see what is being returned.